# How to I get a list of objects from a JSON to an array

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following JSON-structure:

```
{ 
  "markets":
   {
     "Spain":
     {
       key:value,
       key:value,
       key:value
     }, 
    "France":
     {
       key:value,
       key:value,
       key:value
     },          
}
```

and I would like to get list/array of the markets like markets=["Spain","France"] from this.

But I am having a tough time iterating over the markets.

Some of my attempts include using data.markets.foreach and data.markets[index]

But it seems impossible to iterate through the objects in a Json if you dont know their names beforehand.

For reference here is the test code I'm trying things out with:

```
const data = require('../support/steps.json');
var keys = data.markets.foreach(market=>console.log(market));
```

Sorry if this is a trivial thing but I've been unable to find the answer when searching.

PS. I know I get access each market with data.markets["Spain"] etc but the point is that I don't know which countries are there to begin with.

Comment: Just do `Object.keys(data.markets)`, no need to iterate yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get all of the market keys as strings in an array.

```js
const data = { 
  "markets":
   {
     "Spain":
     {
       //...
     }, 
    "France":
     {
       //...
     },       
   }   
};

console.log(Object.keys(data.markets));
```

Comment: THanks, I knew it shoudl be simple!

Answer (score 1):

```js
let data = { 
  "markets":{
     Spain: {}, 
     France:{}          
   }
};

const keys = Object.keys(data.markets)

console.log(keys)
```